# ASP.NET MVC Session and SessionStateBehavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-state

All:

I have been searching high and low for an answer to this, so forgive me if this is a dupe, I just can't seem to find the right answer.

Let's say you have an ASP.NET MVC Controller marked with the    [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
attribute. Does calling actions on this controller "refresh" the session state, keeping it "alive"? Specifically, I have a AJAX request calling a controller to keep the session "alive" since the application is a single page application driven by javascript, and I don't want the users session to die, so every 30 seconds I make a call up to this controller. Similarly, would it stay alive if the controller was marked SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly? Finally, is using an ASP.NET MVC Controller for this purpose not the best way (is there a better way)?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you feel the need to make an ajax call every 30 seconds.  Session state timeout is usually set to a minimum of 10 minutes, often 20 or 30.  I would suggest, however, that you rewrite your app to not depend on Session state staying active, since Session can be reset at any time by IIS for reasons that are out of your control (memory conditions, app pool recycle, exceptions, phase of the moon, etc..).  Instead, save any state you need somewhere, and reload it if the session has timed out since the users last access.

Comment: In most cases, I would agree, but in the current application there is a very large dataset that needs to be kept in the background for the current user. I can't really go into any more detail about it but I do agree with you that 99% of the time you would want to make the application session-free.

Comment: If the data is very large, that makes it even more imperative that you not depend on session.  IIS will randomly kill sessions when memory becomes tight.  If you have large data in session, that's going to guarantee strange, hard to reproduce problems.

Answer (score 0):

Session state will be kept alive automatically with no attributes on the action, depending on how the web.config is configured.  To configure it, see here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

A controller should be okay, but you may want to look into Web API as it'll offer a few more features in this scenario: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Thanks for your response. That is good to know. But what about controllers marked with the [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)] and [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)] attributes? Do calling these actions keep the session alive? That was actually the most important part of my question.

Comment: Ryan, have you ever found out the answer to your question ?